# Copying std::unique_ptr's value via dereferencing

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr, visual-c++-2012

I wrote the following code where I try to copy the value of `unique_ptr` object into a structure.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

struct S {
    S(int X = 0, int Y = 0):x(X), y(Y){}

    // S(const S&) {}
    // S& operator=(const S&) { return *this; }

    int x;
    int y;
    std::unique_ptr<S> ptr;
};

int main() {
    S s;
    s.ptr = std::unique_ptr<S>(new S(1, 4));
    S p = *s.ptr; // Copy the pointer's value
    return 0;
}
```

It pops up errors in Visual C++ 2012:

> IntelliSense: no suitable user-defined conversion from "S" to "S"
>   exists
>   IntelliSense: no operator "=" matches these operands
>   operand types are: std::unique_ptr> = std::unique_ptr>
>   error C2248: 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>::unique_ptr' : cannot access
>   private member declared in class 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>'

Unless I uncomment the lines where I attempted to define a copy constructor and =operator.
This gets rid of the compiler errors but not the IntelliSense errors. It compiles regardless of IntelliSense errors showing in error list.

So, why cannot it just use the default functions and compile with them? Am I doing the copy of value the right way? How should I define the copy constructor if it needs one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The copy constructor is not implicitly generated because you have a user-defined constructor, which is why your attempt to copy an `S` fails.

But still, `unique_ptr` are not copyable, only *movable*, so you can use a **move constructor** for `S` :

```
S(S&& other) : x(other.x), y(other.y), ptr(std::move(other.ptr))
{
      
}
```

And call it :

```
S p = std::move(s); // Move s to p
```

---

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d95757308d9c6f36)

Comment: Is there really no way to copy the value of pointer even on a stack object without sacrificing it? By that I mean leaving `ptr` information alone, and only copying the values of `x` and `y`.

Comment: @cpx The whole point of a `unique_ptr` is that it is unique, so no other object can write to the pointer's memory.  If you want more than one object to reference the memory, you need to use the proper class, probably a `shared_ptr`.

Comment: It is possible to copy the data pointed at by the `unique_ptr`, and to put build that copy inside a new `unique_ptr`. I would argue it's perfectly reasonable also. The original pointer is still 'unique', still the only pointer to that original object. It's OK to have another pointer to a *different* object with the same value. E.g. `auto x1 = make_unique<int>(7); auto x2 = make_unique<int>(7);` **But**, it will lead to slicing (and maybe undefined behaviour) if you try to copy the value at a `unique_ptr<Base>` which is actually pointing to a `Derived`. (There are workarounds for that also.)

Comment: (... but I guess my comment of a few minutes ago doesn't directly apply to this question. `S` itself is non-copyable because it has a `unique_ptr` member. If `S` was copyable, then it would be reasonable (in my opinion) to ask about 'deep-copying' a `unique_ptr<S>`)

Answer (score 2):

`std::unique_ptr` is neither Copy Constructible nor Copy Assignable.

An implicit copy assignment operator and constructor for `S` will be ill formed and hence the error message.

You can however use `S p = std::move(s);` as   `std::unique_ptr` is  Move Constructible and Move Assignable,

Comment: This answer is correct, but I think the circular setup in the question. The real issue is that `S` itself is not copy-constructible or copy-assignable. The reason `S` is problematic is because it has a `unique_ptr<?>` member - the member could be `unique_ptr<T>` instead of `unique_ptr<S>` and it would still lead to the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

> So, why cannot it just use the default functions and compile with them?

As far as I understand, the idea behind [`unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) container is that it solely handles the life of its content (a pointer to `T`), until being relieved from that duty (using `swap` or `reset` methods), or having effectively destroyed its content (when it is itself destroyed). The second important property of `unique_ptr` is that it must allow incomplete types for `T` (so as to support opaque pointers). That means that the contained value may not be *CopyConstructible*. Because of this, `unique_ptr` itself cannot be allowed to be *CopyConstructible*.

> Am I doing the copy of value the right way?
>   How should I define the copy constructor if it needs one?

If `T` ends up being *CopyConstructible*, as you want to do it, you must handle the copy by hand, by accessing the pointer, as you are doing it in `main`. The copy constructor should probably do the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Not a complete answer, just informational:

I highly recommend adding visibility into your experiment:

```
std::ostream&
operator<<(std::ostream& os, const S& s)
{
    os << '{' << s.x << ", " << s.y << ", ";
    if (s.ptr != nullptr)
        os << s.ptr.get() << ':' << *s.ptr;
    else
        os << "nullptr";
    return os << '}';
}
```

Now you can say things like:

```
cout << "s = " << s << '\n';
```

at multiple places in your experiment, and really get a good visual on what is happening after each step.  This should help you analyze and continue in your design.