# Dereferencing a copying the value of a unique_ptr

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I have a function that is given a unique_ptr to a string.  I want to copy that value is lambdas and use it to invoke functions that take std::string.  Is what I am doing below the right way to do this:

```
void someFunc(std::unique_ptr<std::string> id) {
    const std::string idStr = *id;
    stream.subscribe([=](auto arg1) { arg1.invoke(idStr); });
}
```

What I want to do is just copy the string into a new location.  Don't care about the id unique_ptr at that point.  I found [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26573972/copying-stdunique-ptrs-value-via-dereferencing) that says that seems to indicate that I can do the following:

```
std::string idStr = std::move(id);
```

However, that does't actually work for me.  It fails with "no viable conversion" error.

Comment: `std::string idStr = std::move(id);` can't work when if is an `std::unqiue_ptr`. I think, you misunderstand the question.

Comment: `std::string idStr = *id;`

Comment: @SergeyA  I know it's not working for me.  However, your comment doesn't make sense to me.  In the linked discussion, it is also a unique_ptr.  In any case, what I am asking here is what I am doing (idStr = *id) is doing what I think it does and is the right way for me to move forward.

Comment: I do not understand what is the question. I have no idea if what you are doing is *right* or *wrong*, since you didn't tell us anything about your use case. What is the `stream`, what is the `subscribe`, what is the `invoke`?

Comment: `void someFunc(std::unique_ptr<std::string> id)` is a bizarre function signature.  Since the `unique_ptr` is passed by value that means the call site is giving up ownership to it.  If you don't care about it, you aren't using it for anything, then why even take a `unique_ptr`.  You could just have `someFunc` take a string by value and move it into the lambda.

Comment: @Pratik `in the linked discussion, it is also a unique_ptr.` No, `S s;` is not a unique pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a function that is given a unique_ptr to a string. I want to copy that value
>
> ```
> void someFunc(std::unique_ptr<std::string> id) {
>     const std::string idStr = *id;
> ```
>
> What I want to do is just copy the string into a new location.

That is a correct way to copy the pointed string, yes.

> ... that I can do the following:
>
> ```
> std::string idStr = std::move(id);
> ```

That is ill-formed. You cannot do that. The examples in the linked question do not do that.